# How do I run ant from within the _Events.groovy script using the AntBuilder?

Tags: grails, ant, groovy, build

I am trying to automate a build process that involves looping over a few directories and running "ant all" on all of them. All of them have a a simple build.xml.

I can do this via a shell script but I am using other stuff from within Groovy, for example, using the UI Performance Grails Plugin, so would like to stick to Groovy.

All documentation/forums on the web/other questions on SO, talk about running ant.exec and other AntBuilder methods but I didn't get to run a simple ant all.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following example.

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()

ant.fileset(id:"builds", dir:".", includes:"**/build.xml")

ant.project.references.builds.each {
    ant.project.log "Building ${it}"
    ant.ant(antfile:it, target:"all")
}
```

Works for me as a standalone groovy script (I haven't tried calling it from grails)

Comment: Thanks @mark-oconnor, I found a simpler way though, using subant, as in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler way, using a subant task. Something like this:

```
ant.subant(target:"all") {
    fileset(dir:"${pathToBuildDir}" includes:"build.xml") 
}
```